# Crashlytics log shows java file line number instead of cs file

Tags: xamarin.android, crashlytics

I am working on a `Xamarin.Android` native application and we write the code in `.cs` file. We have integrated Crashlytics as well. We are receiving Exception on Crashlytics but the line number is shown for .java file instead of .cs file and it just doesn't make any sense. The crash is not occurring on our device. Is there any way of getting the crashes with .cs file line number? My Activity name is `MyActivity.cs` but in the stack trace, it is showing `MyActivity.java`.

StackTrace

```
Fatal Exception: md5bcaacea39e485ed8e3d7f0e2edda77a7.MonoExceptionHelper: (NullReferenceException) Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at md8340a283ba8745f8993ee3dff35d08f0.MyActivity.n_onCreate(MyActivity.java)
   at md8340a283ba8745f8993ee3dff35d08f0.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:29)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is all the `StackTrace`? I have a feeling this is missing something

Comment: Yes, it is not complete stack trace, but I want the stacktrace to point cs file line number instead of java file. Will complete stackTrace help?

Comment: Why not check the complete stacktrace that should have what you are looking for